# Existe alguna palabra adaptada al español, o término equivalente, que exprese el significado del neologismo inglés "ratioed"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, neologismos, jerga-internet

Según Wiktionary

> [**ratioed**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ratioed)
>
> *neologismo, internet*
>
> De un tweet en Twitter, tener
> significativamente más respuestas que retweets o "me gusta", indicando
> rechazo general del público.

¿Existe alguna adaptación al español de esta palabra? ¿O algún término equivalente que exprese lo mismo o algo similar?

Comment: Desproporcionado

Answer (score 1):

Sinceramente después de revisar varios foros y echarle cabeza, creo que puedo decir que no.

Una de las mejores características del inglés es que prácticamente cualquier sustantivo se puede convertir en verbo, por ejemplo con la palabra aquí expuesta: 'ratio', a la cual le agregamos -ed y tenemos el verbo.

Lo mismo sucede con otros verbos en inglés, ya sea por que la traducción requiere más de una palabra, o la traducción directa no funciona bien. De esta última un ejemplo es el verbo 'lock'. 'Lock' puede traducirse como dejar fijo en una posición (lock the parts together) pero puede ser a lo que le llamamos 'echar llave' (lock the door/echarle llave a la puerta).

Answer (score 1):

Definitivamente no hay un término con la especificidad contextual con la que el termino `ratioed` en la web moderna se usa, donde los usuarios interactuan con contenidos calificables por terceros . Que un post/tweet/comentario devengue "`ratioed`" signfica que (en la practica) fue

> desaprobado / mal-aceptado / rechazado / amonestado

Esto es porque el [ratio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ratio#English) —la proporción aludida— representa el `numero de comentarios` en relación a los `likes` aprobatorios

```
          número de comentarios 
  ratio = ---------------------
          número de likes
```

Así el valor de esa proporción va a ser más alto al aumentar el numero de comentario (seguramente críticos) por encima de los likes ("me-gustan") de un contenido publicado y sometido a reacciones.

En castellano no se usa la traducción literal de ***ratioed*** para implicar que el post/tweet o publicación resultara, por tanto asi, **desbalanceado** , **desproporcionado** en sus reacciones negativas